# Site for general language questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What site should I ask questions about language *in general*?

Example:

> When does a dialect become a separate language?

The only site I could think of was [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I expect [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) is what you're looking for.

> The Linguistics Stack Exchange Site is a Q&A for *linguists, language enthusiasts and people who have some interest in how languages work.* What is Linguistics? It is the **scientific study of languages.**